# What is the number of n node simple labeled graphs without endpoints?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

Here, an endpoint is a vertex of degree $1$.  For $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ the number of such graphs is $1,1,2,15,314,\ldots\;$.  This is sequence [A059167](http://oeis.org/A059167) in Sloane's OEIS.  The exponential generating function (e.g.f.) is given in the OEIS entry:

$$\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{x}{e^x}\right)^n2^{\binom{n}2}$$

Is there some way to easily arrive at the generating function by applying symbolic derivation methods such as those described in Flajolet and Sedgewick Analytic Combinatorics?

I understand the factor $\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})$.  I also see that the summation WITHOUT THE FACTOR $\exp(-x)$ would be the e.g.f. for the total number of simple labeled graphs.

Comment: You should really be using [MathJax to make your post more readable](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is a really good question. I hope someone can answer it.

Comment: The problem is the $\frac{x}{e^x}$ factor plugged in to the EGF for labeled graphs, which doesn't count anything because it has negative coefficients. I also don't see what the $\exp(x^2/2)$ corresponds to...note that, removing it, the remaining series has negative coefficients so doesn't count anything meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remark.**  The [OEIS entry  A059167](https://oeis.org/A059167) sends
us to Harary and Palmer,  *Graphical Enumeration*, which in turn sends
us to *Some unusual enumeration  problems* by Read. There really is no
reason not to consult these sources.

Here  are some  ideas on  the  subject.  Let  $\mathcal{G}$ be  the
species  of all  labeled graphs  and $\mathcal{A}$  be the  species of
labeled graphs with  no endpoints and $\mathcal{B}$ be  the species of
connected labeled graphs with  no endpoints. Finally let $\mathcal{T}$
be the species of rooted labeled trees.  Also introduce $\mathcal{U},$
unrooted labeled trees. We have by inspection that

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{G} = \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U} + 
\mathcal{B}_{\ge 3}(\mathcal{T}))
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathcal{A} = \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{B})$$

Translating to generating functions we get

$$G(z) = \exp(U(z) + B_{\ge 3}(T(z))
\quad\text{and}\quad
A(z) = \exp(B(z)).$$

and the goal is to compute $A(z).$ We get for $G(z)$

$$G(z) = 
\exp\left(U(z)  - T(z) +  B(T(z))\right)
\\ = 
\exp\left(U(z)  - T(z) +  \log A(T(z))\right)
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{n\choose 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Here we have made use of  the fact that the number of connected graphs
with no endpoints is one for the singleton node and zero for graphs on
two nodes.

Now we have for $\mathcal{T}$ that

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$

which yields

$$T(z) = z \exp T(z)
\quad \text{or} \quad z = T(z) \exp (-T(z)).$$

Furthermore we have combinatorially

$$T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\quad \text{and} \quad 
U(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-2} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

We now claim that 
$$U(z) = T(z) - \frac{1}{2} T(z)^2.$$

This  yields for  the coefficient  $[z^n] U(z)$  where $n\ge  1$

$$[z^n] U(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\left(T(z) - \frac{1}{2} T(z)^2\right) \; dz.$$

Using $T(z) = w$ and $z = w \exp(-w)$ and $dz = (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w))
\; dw$ we obtain (this is a standard computation)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp((n+1)w)}{w^{n+1}} 
\left(w-\frac{1}{2}w^2\right)
\exp(-w) (1-w)
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(nw)}{w^{n}} 
\left(\frac{1}{2} w^2 - \frac{3}{2} w + 1\right)
\; dw.$$

This is for $n\ge 3$ (the small $n$ are left to the reader)

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{n^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}
- \frac{3}{2}\frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}
+ \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
\\ = \frac{n^{n-2}}{n!}
\times \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n}
- \frac{3}{2} n (n-1)
+ n^2\right) = \frac{n^{n-2}}{n!}.$$

This verifies the claim. Use this on $G(z)$ to get

$$G(z) = 
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}T(z)^2 
+ \log A(T(z))\right) = A(T(z)) \exp(-T(z)^2/2)$$

or

$$A(T(z)) = G(z) \exp(T(z)^2/2).$$

In order to  conclude we put $T(z)=w$ and  use the functional equation
of $T(z)$ which yields $z=w/\exp(w)$ to obtain

$$A(w) = G(w/\exp(w)) \exp(w^2/2).$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
A(w) = \exp\left(\frac{w^2}{2}\right)
\sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\frac{w}{e^w}\right)^n \frac{2^{n\choose 2}}{n!}.}$$

The following  memory-efficient Perl  script computes the  first eight
values for comparison with the generating function.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub enumerate {
    my ($n, $deg, $sofar, $data, 
        $pos, $match, $verif) = @_;

    my $vert;
    if($verif == 1){
        for($vert=1; $vert <= $n; $vert++){
            last if $deg->[$vert] == 1;
        }

        $$match++ if $vert == $n+1;
    }

    return if $pos >= scalar(@$data);

    return if $pos > 0 &&
        $data->[$pos]->[0] > $data->[$pos-1]->[0] &&
        $deg->[$data->[$pos-1]->[0]] == 1;

    enumerate($n, $deg, $sofar, $data, $pos+1, $match, 0);

    my ($u, $v) = @{$data->[$pos]};

    $deg->[$u]++; $deg->[$v]++;
    push @$sofar, $data->[$pos];

    enumerate($n, $deg, $sofar, $data, $pos+1, $match, 1);

    pop @$sofar;
    $deg->[$u]--; $deg->[$v]--;

    1;
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = int(shift || 5);

     for(my $n=1; $n <= $mx; $n++){
         my @srcdata;

         for(my $u=1; $u <= $n; $u++){
             for(my $v=$u+1; $v <= $n; $v++){
                 push @srcdata, [$u, $v];
             }
         }

         my $noendp = 0; my @degsrc = (0) x ($n+1);
         enumerate($n, \@degsrc, [], 
                   \@srcdata, 0, \$noendp, 1);

         print "$n: $noendp\n";
     }

     1;
}
```

The output was the following table:

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 15
5: 314
6: 13757
7: 1142968
8: 178281041
```

On the other hand Maple says:

```
> XGF := exp(z^2/2)*add((z/exp(z))^n*2^binomial(n,2)/n!, n=0..12):
> seq(n!*coeftayl(XGF, z=0, n), n=0..8);
                  1, 1, 1, 2, 15, 314, 13757, 1142968, 178281041
```

We would use recurrence relations to extract higher values.

**Addendum, Sep  26, 2016.** As per  request we now treat  the case of
graphs having one endpoint. The species equation now becomes

$$\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \textsc{SET}(-\mathcal{Z} 
+ \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{Z}))^{\Large\star}
\times \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{Z}).$$

This reads from left to right (the star denotes marking), first, a set
of  singletons, second  a set  of connected  graphs with  no endpoints
where  a   node  is   marked  and  third,   a  rooted   path  (species
$\mathcal{P}$), not  empty, that is  attached at the marked  node. Now
observe that there are $n!$ rooted paths on $n$ nodes and hence

$$P(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n! \frac{z^n}{n!} = \frac{z}{1-z}.$$

We thus obtain for the generating function (we mark using the operator
$z\frac{d}{dz}$)

$$\exp(z) \frac{z}{1-z} 
z \left(\exp \left(-z + \log A(z)\right)\right)'
\\ = \exp(z) \frac{z}{1-z} 
z \left(A(z) \exp(-z)\right)'
\\ = \exp(z) \frac{z}{1-z} 
z (A'(z) \exp(-z) - A(z) \exp(-z))
\\ = \frac{z^2}{1-z} (A'(z)-A(z)).$$

These data  can be  verified with the  following Perl script  (not the
simplest possible but optimized to produce the value for $n=8$).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub enumerate {
    my ($n, $k, $endp, $deg, $sofar, $data, 
        $pos, $match, $verif) = @_;

    $$match++ if ($verif == 1 && $endp == $k);

    return if $pos >= scalar(@$data);

    if($pos > 0 &&
       $data->[$pos]->[0] > $data->[$pos-1]->[0]){
        my $epcount = 0;

        for(my $vert = 1; 
            $vert < $data->[$pos]->[0]; $vert++){
            $epcount++ if $deg->[$vert] == 1;
        }

        return if $epcount > $k;
    }

    enumerate($n, $k, $endp, $deg, 
              $sofar, $data, $pos+1, $match, 0);

    my ($u, $v) = @{$data->[$pos]};

    $deg->[$u]++; $deg->[$v]++;

    $endp++ if $deg->[$u] == 1;
    $endp-- if $deg->[$u] == 2;

    $endp++ if $deg->[$v] == 1;
    $endp-- if $deg->[$v] == 2;    

    push @$sofar, $data->[$pos];

    enumerate($n, $k, $endp, $deg, 
              $sofar, $data, $pos+1, $match, 1);

    pop @$sofar;

    $endp-- if $deg->[$u] == 1;
    $endp++ if $deg->[$u] == 2;

    $endp-- if $deg->[$v] == 1;
    $endp++ if $deg->[$v] == 2;    

    $deg->[$u]--; $deg->[$v]--;

    1;
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = int(shift || 5);
     my $epsrch = int(shift || 0);

     for(my $n=1; $n <= $mx; $n++){
         my @srcdata;

         for(my $u=1; $u <= $n; $u++){
             for(my $v=$u+1; $v <= $n; $v++){
                 push @srcdata, [$u, $v];
             }
         }

         my $noendp = 0; my @degsrc = (0) x ($n+1);
         enumerate($n, $epsrch, 0, \@degsrc, [], 
                   \@srcdata, 0, \$noendp, 1);

         print "$n: $noendp\n";
     }

     1;
}
```

This produced the following table:

```
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 12
5: 320
6: 10890
7: 640836
8: 68362504
```

Maple says:

```
> XS := series(z^2/(1-z)*(diff(XGF, z)-XGF), z=0, 9):
> seq(n!*coeff(XS, z, n), n=1..8);
                   0, 0, 0, 12, 320, 10890, 640836, 68362504
```

We can also  treat the problem of enumerating  labeled graphs with two
endpoints. Now there are three cases: first case, a set of singletons,
an  unrooted  path on  at  least  two nodes  and  a  set of  connected
components with no endpoints. We get

$$\exp(z) \times \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{1-z} 
\times \exp(-z + \log A(z))
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{1-z} A(z).$$

Second,  a set  of singletons  and two  rooted paths  attached  to two
different nodes from a set  of connected components with no endpoints.
This yields

$$\exp(z) \times \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2} \times
\frac{1}{2} z^2 \frac{d}{dz} \frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z + \log A(z))
\\ = \exp(z) \times \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2} \times
\frac{1}{2} z^2 \frac{d}{dz} \frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z) A(z)
\\ = \exp(z) \times \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2} \times
\frac{1}{2} z^2 \frac{d}{dz} (\exp(-z) A'(z) - \exp(-z) A(z))
\\ = \exp(z) \times \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2} \\ \times
\frac{1}{2} z^2 (\exp(-z) A''(z) - 2\exp(-z) A'(z) + \exp(-z) A(z))
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^4}{(1-z)^2} (A''(z) - 2A'(z) + A(z)).$$

Third, a set of  singletons and a fork attached to a  node of a set of
connected components with no endpoints. The fork is

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2}$$

(the first term is the handle) which yields

$$\exp(z) \times \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^3}
\times z\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z + \log A(z))
\\ = \exp(z) \times \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^3}
\times z\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z) A(z)
\\ = \exp(z) \times \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^3}
\times z(\exp(-z) A'(z) - \exp(-z) A(z))
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^3}{(1-z)^3} (A'(z) - A(z)).$$

Collecting everything we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{1-z} A(z)
\\ + \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^4}{(1-z)^2} (A''(z) - 2A'(z) + A(z))
\\ + \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^3}{(1-z)^3} (A'(z) - A(z)).$$

The Perl script will produce the following table:

```
1: 0
2: 1
3: 6
4: 30
5: 260
6: 5445
7: 228564
8: 17288852
```

while Maple says:

```
> K1 := 1/2*z^2/(1-z)*XGF:
> K2 := 1/2*z^4/(1-z)^2*(diff(XGF, z$2)-2*diff(XGF,z)+XGF):
> K3 := 1/2*z^3/(1-z)^3*(diff(XGF, z)-XGF):
> XS := series(K1+K2+K3, z=0, 9):
> seq(n!*coeff(XS, z, n), n=1..8);
                   0, 1, 6, 30, 260, 5445, 228564, 17288852
```

All of  these need careful checking  as it is possible  that errors in
the species decomposition might only become apparent with large values
of $n.$

**Addendum,  Sep 27, 2016.**  To enhance  this post  and make  it more
useful   we   now   treat    the   case   of   graphs   having   three
endpoints. *Observe that these  calculations are conjectural in nature
and require  independent verification, most  likely through recurrence
relations.*

First case, set of singletons, a  star (union of three paths) and a
set of connected components with no endpoints. We get

$$\exp(z)\times \frac{1}{6} z \frac{z^3}{(1-z)^3} \times
\exp(-z+\log A(z))
= \frac{1}{6} \frac{z^4}{(1-z)^3} A(z).$$

Second  case, a  set of  singletons,  an unrooted  path and  a set  of
connected  components  with  one  node  marked  to  which  a  path  is
attached. We have

$$\exp(z)\times \frac{1}{2}\frac{z^2}{1-z} \times
\frac{z}{1-z} \times z\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z+\log A(z))
\\ = \frac{1}{2}\frac{z^4}{(1-z)^2} (A'(z)-A(z)).$$

Third case,  a set  of singletons and  three rooted paths  attached to
three  marked nodes  from  the  set of  connected  components with  no
endpoints.

$$\exp(z)\times \frac{z^3}{(1-z)^3} \times
\frac{1}{6} z^3\frac{d}{dz}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z+\log A(z))
\\ = \frac{1}{6} \frac{z^6}{(1-z)^3} (A'''(z)-3A''(z)+3A'(z)-A(z)).$$

Fourth case, a set of singletons, a rooted path and a fork attached to
two marked sites  among the components with no  endpoints (no symmetry
between the path and the fork):

$$\exp(z) \times \frac{z}{1-z} \times 
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2}
\times z^2 \frac{d}{dz}\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z+\log A(z))
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^5}{(1-z)^4}
(A''(z)-2A'(z)+A(z)).$$

Fifth case,  singletons, and a triple  fork attached to  a marked site
among the components with no endpoints.

$$\exp(z)\times \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{1-z}\frac{z^3}{(1-z)^3}
\times z\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z+\log A(z))
\\= \frac{1}{6} \frac{z^4}{(1-z)^4} (A'(z)-A(z)).$$

Finally, a repeat, but with the fork branching two times, which is the
handle, possibly empty, to which  are attached two paths, one of which
forks:

$$\frac{1}{1-z} \times \frac{z}{1-z}
\frac{z}{1-z} \times \frac{1}{2} \frac{z}{1-z}\frac{z}{1-z}$$

for a contribution of

$$\exp(z)\times \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^4}{(1-z)^5}
\times z\frac{d}{dz} \exp(-z+\log A(z))
\\= \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^5}{(1-z)^5} (A'(z)-A(z)).$$

Collect these six to get the desired EGF.

Here the Perl script will produce the table

```
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 4
5: 80
6: 1860
7: 64680
8: 3666600
```

and Maple says

```
> K1 := 1/6*z^4/(1-z)^3*XGF:
> K2 := 1/2*z^4/(1-z)^2*(diff(XGF,z)-XGF):
> K3 := 1/6*z^6/(1-z)^3*(diff(XGF, z$3)-3*diff(XGF, z$2)+3*diff(XGF,z)-XGF):
> K4 := 1/2*z^5/(1-z)^4*(diff(XGF, z$2)-2*diff(XGF,z)+XGF):
> K5 := 1/6*z^4/(1-z)^4*(diff(XGF,z)-XGF):
> K6 := 1/2*z^5/(1-z)^5*(diff(XGF,z)-XGF):
> XS := series(K1+K2+K3+K4+K5+K6, z=0, 9):
> seq(n!*coeff(XS, z, n), n=1..8);
                       0, 0, 0, 4, 80, 1860, 64680, 3666600
```

Comment: @ Marko Riedel. Thank you.  I was going to suggest that you add this as a link in the OEIS entry but I see that you have.  This will be very helpful to a lot of people as it was for me.

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark. I enjoyed consulting the paper by Read referenced by Harary which is from an era where some mathematical papers were typeset on a typewriter. (Difficult to imagine a world without LaTeX, just think how error-prone this process must have been especially if the author did not typeset their own paper.) Nonetheless all the ideas presented above are already present in this work (the paper by Read).

Comment: As a follow-up question: I want to count the number of labeled graphs with exactly one vertex of degree one.  Would you agree that the e.g.f. is:

Comment: A(z) * z * z * d[B(z) - z]/dz   For n=0,1,2,...  this gives the coefficients 0,0,0,0,12,260,8970.  But this sequence is not in OEIS.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this additional problem and returning to what we have, in fact there were some issues with what I had posted which are now fixed. I hope you will be able to verify the generating function for the case of one endpoint.

Comment: I have also treated the case of two endpoints.

Comment: In the second sentence in the Addendum.  You have "... first, a set of singletons ...  I think it should be a set of connected graphs with no endpoints.  In other words I think the e.g.f is A(z)*z/(1-z)*z*d[B(z)-z)]/dz.

Comment: I will look into this but note that the series from your EGF produces $72$  graphs with no endpoints on four nodes, which is more than the $2^{4\choose 2} =64$ available  graphs, so it cannot possibly be right. Did you notice that my data from the Perl script match the EGF?

Comment: Using the e.g.f : A(z)*z/(1-z)*z*d[B(z)-z)]/dz.  I get the first few terms  (indexed from n=0):  0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 320, 10890, 640836, 68362504, 13369203792, 4852623272670, 3314874720579180, 4318786169776866612, 10854838945689940034808.   I verified the terms for n=4,5,6,7 using Mathematica's built in graph data.  I also verified the cases up to n=7  for graphs with exactly 2 endpoints with what you have posted above.

Comment: I must have made a mistake when I computed the series. Using what I have $$\frac{z^2}{1-z} (A'(z)-A(z))$$ and $A(z) = \exp B(z)$ we obtain $$\frac{z^2}{1-z} (A(z) B'(z) - A(z)) = \frac{z^2}{1-z} A(z) \frac{d}{dz} (B(z)-z)$$ which is your version. Perfect. Of course your species equation is correct too. Do you want to write the two OEIS entries (one endpoint, two endpoints) or should I?

Comment: In case you are interested I went through my archives and discovered I had made a mistake entering your EGF into Maple. Maple agrees with your data once the error is corrected.

Comment: I present the case of three endpoints for your consideration.

Comment: @ Marko Riedel. Thanks for your excellent work here.  If you will submit these sequences to OEIS I will add a Mathematica code and perhaps an example that might embellish the entries.

Comment: These three are now in the draft queue with IDs A277072, A277073, A277074.

Comment: I do hope with them being visible on the OEIS that someone checks my work on three endpoints, possibly with a diagram of the six cases.

Comment: I do not understand your species equation for graphs with exactly one endpoint.  You write "This reads from left to right (the star denotes marking), first, a set of singletons, second a set of connected graphs with no endpoints where a node is marked and third, a rooted path (species P), not empty, that is attached at the marked node."  How does this give us a graph with one endpoint?  The species equation translation for my e.g.f would read:  A set of connected graphs with no endpoints with exactly one such graph (of size 3 or more) having marked vertices to which a rooted path is joined.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to say, I thought this follows by inspection. The one endpoint is of course the free end of the path. We cannot attach to the singletons because that would produce two endpoints.

Comment: OK, I just now "got it".  You are right.  It does follow by inspection.  It is interesting to note the two different ways to make the construction.