# A $\Gamma$- function identity: $\sum_{j=0}^m \frac{\Gamma(x-j)\Gamma(m-x+j)}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(m-j+1)} = 0$

Tags: gamma-function

Mathematica told me the following identity,

$$x\notin \mathbb{Z}, \quad m\in \mathbb{Z}^+,\quad  \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{\Gamma(x-j)\Gamma(m-x+j)}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(m-j+1)} = 0 .$$

I tried to prove it but not successful. Could anyone please take a look at the above identity?

I rearranged it to the form,
$$ \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x} \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^{j} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}(i+j-x)}{j!(m-j)!}$$
but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What did you try ?.

Comment: I added what I have tried. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose  we seek  to  prove that  for $x$  not  an integer  and $m$  a
positive integer

$$\sum_{q=0}^m 
\frac{\Gamma(x-q)\Gamma(m-x+q)}{\Gamma(q+1)\Gamma(m-q+1)} = 0.$$

We have

$$\Gamma(x-q) \prod_{p=1}^{q} (x-p) = \Gamma(x)$$

and

$$\Gamma(m-x+q) = \Gamma(1-x) \prod_{p=1}^{m+q-1} (p-x).$$

This yields for the sum

$$\frac{1}{m!} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q}
\frac{\prod_{p=1}^{m+q-1} (p-x)}{\prod_{p=1}^{q} (x-p)}
\\ = \frac{1}{m!} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{\prod_{p=1}^{m+q-1} (p-x)}{\prod_{p=1}^{q} (p-x)}
\\ = \frac{1}{m!} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} (-1)^q
\prod_{p=q+1}^{m+q-1} (p-x)
\\ = \frac{1}{m} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} (-1)^q
{m+q-1-x\choose m-1}.$$

Introduce

$${m+q-1-x\choose m-1} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}}
(1+z)^{m+q-1-x}
\; dz.$$

We get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}}
(1+z)^{m-1-x}
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} (-1)^q (1+z)^q
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}}
(1+z)^{m-1-x}
(-z)^m
\; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
(1+z)^{m-1-x}
\; dz = 0.$$

This is the claim.

**Remark.**   To  ensure   the  integrand   being  analytic   in  a
neighborhood of zero  (recall that $x$ is not an  integer) we may take
e.g.  $(1+z)^\alpha = \exp(\alpha\log(1+z))$ with the principal branch
of the logarithm that has argument from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ (branch cut on
the  negative real  axis). We  can  multiply two  powers $\alpha$  and
$\beta$ of  $1+z$ as long as we  use the same branch  of the logarithm
throughout.

Even better we can use  the formal power series definition to prove
that   $$(1+z)^\alpha  (1+z)^\beta   =   (1+z)^{\alpha+\beta}$$  where
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not integers. We get

$$[z^n] (1+z)^\alpha (1+z)^\beta =
\sum_{p=0}^n {\alpha \choose p} {\beta \choose n-p}
\\ = \frac{1}{n!} 
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} \alpha^{\underline{p}}
\beta^{\underline{n-p}}.$$

The coefficient here on $\alpha^{p_1} \beta^{p_2}$ is

$$\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p}
(-1)^{p_1+p} \left[p\atop p_1\right]
(-1)^{p_2+n-p} \left[n-p\atop p_2\right]
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n+p_1+p_2}}{n!} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p}
\left[p\atop p_1\right]
\left[n-p\atop p_2\right].$$

On the other hand we have

$$[\alpha^{p_1} \beta^{p_2}] {\alpha+\beta\choose n}
= [\alpha^{p_1} \beta^{p_2}] \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{p=0}^n 
(\alpha+\beta)^p (-1)^{n+p} \left[n\atop p\right]
\\ = \frac{1}{n!} {p_1+p_2\choose p_1}
(-1)^{n+p_1+p_2} \left[n\atop p_1+p_2\right].$$

The quantity other  than the sign and the  factorial counts the number
of ways we  can partition $[n]$ into $p_1$ red  and $p_2$ blue cycles,
using everything. The sum says we first pick the values that will form
the  red  cycles  and  partition  them into  $p_1$  cycles.   Then  we
partition the remaining values, which will be blue, into $p_2$ cycles.
The closed formula  says that we first partition  $[n]$ into $p_1+p_2$
cycles and  then choose the $p_1$  red cycles, leaving  the rest blue.
This concludes the  argument where we have not  used complex variables
and/or branches of the logarithm.

Comment: (+1) How much do you like analytic combinatorics? ;D

Comment: I don't quite understand, I am a real fan of analytical combinatorics, see this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930410). There are times nonetheless when a combinatorial argument can be simpler and more robust than complex variables.

Comment: Nothing to understand, it was just a way for stating that you're really good at it.

Comment: Thank you for these kind words. I have seen many of your remarkable posts and I enjoy the eureka effect that some of them have, even to the point of refraining myself from posting work that mostly consists of algebraic manipulations even though it might be correct. A lot of algebra is a kind of flag indicating one should look for a more elegant solution. The Egorychev method in particular can produce complicated expressions quickly, which is a signal to investigate a different path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The use of complex integral is really smart. I did not understand your last paragraph, could you please explain a bit more? the number of ways we can partition $[n]$ into $p_1$ red and $p_2$ blue cycles, using everything ?? What does it mean by red cycles and blue cycles ?

Comment: [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) count labeled partitions into cycles.